# How to split an entity in Core Data migration mapping

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-data-migration, mapping-model

It seems like this should be straight forward but I have not been able to find a good example of it.  I have a simple Core Data entity that I want to split into two separate entities.  Apple's documentation mentions it at a high level ([Mapping Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004735-SW1)), however, it is unclear what the actual mapping model should look like to associate the relationship to the new split out entity back to the original.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I have found my own answer to this one and have detailed it in this blog post: https://slalomdotcom.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/splitting-an-entity-in-a-coredata-migration/

Comment: I get a server not found error when I click on that link. Is it just me?

Comment: Awesome! Gave you mad up rep.

Comment: Just note how relationship is set back in second picture. And if actual Xcode project would help, I used it here: https://github.com/coodly/ios-gambrinus